# Adjust column width in RangetoHTML for Outlook

Tags: html, excel, vba

I send emails automatically from Excel.

Sometimes the third column ends up completely at the right, outside the mail-window of the receiver (while I autofit the cells before I use RangetoHTML).

It seems that the width of the second column is set much wider or that the third column is set wider and aligned right.

The thing is that it doesn't happen every time. Adjusting the row heights is easily done but not the column width.

How do I keep the width formatting constant in RangetoHTML?

```vb
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook
Dim R As Long

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
'Publish the sheet to a html file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
     Cells(1).Select
     Cells(1).EntireRow.AutoFit
     Cells(1).EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
```

Comment: Where does that code go? Show the entire code with your edit.

Comment: Typically adding a bit of explanation to your answers instead of just "try this" goes a long way. Explain *why* the user should "try this". Why is this better than what is currently being done? How does it solve the problem.